# TypeScript setTimeout loop passing this error

Tags: javascript, function, class, typescript, timeout

Trying to create a timer loop in TypeScript:

```
timeout() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('Test');
        this.timeout();
    }, 1000/60);
}
```

But after the first loop works correctly I'm getting this error: "Uncaught TypeError: this.timeout is not a function". It seems that the this variable does not exist after the initial loop. Any ideas?

Comment: If you use arrow functions (`=>`) instead of `function` then the `this` context will be captured inside the nested function automatically.  Useful docs: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html and https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html

Answer (score 41):

Because your `this` doesn't refer to the object. Every function has it's own this. So your `this` is the one which is defined by anonymous function inside the `setTimeout()`.

To make your program work, you need to hold the `this` before the timeout and use throught that variable.

```js
class Test {
  
  timeout() {
      var that = this;
      setTimeout(function () {
          console.log('Test');
          that.timeout();
      }, 1000/60);
  } 
  
}


let t = new Test();
t.timeout();
```

Or you can work with `lambda functions`, which will keep the `this` to your object.`Lamda`'s `this` will refer to the outer's `this`, which call the lambda function`.

```js
class Test {
      
   timeout() {
       setTimeout(() => {
           console.log('Test');
           this.timeout();
       }, 1000/60);
   } 
      
}


let t = new Test();
t.timeout();
```

Answer (score 12):

Because of this context is lost. Use the arrow function this is better.

```
timeout() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Test');
        this.timeout();
    }, 1000/60);
}
```